# Задействовать вложенные условия

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

У меня есть множество условий. Когда пользователь отправляет сообщение в группу, то ему отвечает бот.

Проблема заключается в том, что, когда пользователь вводит цифру 1, то ему выводится еще 3 варианта ответа, но после этого вложенные условия пользователь уже не может выбрать так как цикл начнется заново и за место вложенных будут проверяться основные условия.

Как я могу начать проверять вложенные условия, если пользователь выберет цифру один(первое основное условие)?

```
while True:
    for event in longpoll.listen():
        if event.from_user and not event.from_me:
        if response == "1":
            vk_session.method('messages.send',
                             {'user_id': event.user_id, 'message': 'Здравствуй\n'
                                                            '1. да\n2. нет\n 3. Не знаю', 'random_id': 0})
            if response == "1":
                vk_session.method('messages.send',
                                  {'user_id': event.user_id, 'message': '...', 'random_id': 0})
            elif response == "2":
                vk_session.method('messages.send',
                                  {'user_id': event.user_id, 'message': '...', 'random_id': 0})
            elif response == "3":
                vk_session.method('messages.send',
                                  {'user_id': event.user_id, 'message': '...', 'random_id': 0})
            else:
                vk_session.method('messages.send',
                                  {'user_id': event.user_id, 'message': 'Я вас не понял, выберите один из трех вариантов(укажите подходящую цифру)', 'random_id': 0})
            list_output()
        elif response == "2":
            vk_session.method('messages.send',
                              {'user_id': event.user_id, 'message': 'Пока, друг!', 'random_id': 0})
        else:
            vk_session.method('messages.send',
                              {'user_id': event.user_id, 'message': 'Я вас не понял', 'random_id': 0})
```

Comment: Нифига непонятно. В чем проблема с приведённым кодом?

Comment: @Эникейщик, ему нужно чтобы после того как будет отправлено сообщение (строка 5), скрипт должен подождать ответа и следовать следующему вложенному блоку (начиная от строки 8) if..else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я думаю что можно создать список и вносить туда пользователей от которых мы ожидаем ответа.

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll


LOGIN, PASSWORD = 'python@vk.com', 'mypassword'
IDKU = 'Я вас не понял, выберите один из трех вариантов' + \
    '(укажите подходящую цифру)'

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(LOGIN, PASSWORD)
wait_next_round = []  # Users list


def list_output():
    pass


def next_round(response, _id):
    if response == "1":
        vk_session.method('messages.send',
                          {'user_id': _id,
                           'message': '...',
                           'random_id': 0})
    elif response == "2":
        vk_session.method('messages.send',
                          {'user_id': _id,
                           'message': '...',
                           'random_id': 0})
    elif response == "3":
        vk_session.method('messages.send',
                          {'user_id': _id,
                           'message': '...',
                           'random_id': 0})
    else:
        vk_session.method('messages.send',
                          {'user_id': _id,
                           'message': '...',
                           'random_id': 0})

    wait_next_round.remove(_id)
    list_output()


def main():
    # Допустим это тело программы где цикл

    try:
        vk_session.auth(token_only=True)
    except vk_api.AuthError as error_msg:
        print(error_msg)
        return

    longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)

    while True:
        for event in longpoll.listen():
            if event.from_user and not event.from_me:
                if event.user_id in wait_next_round:
                    next_round(event.text, event.user_id)
                else:
                    if event.text == "1":
                        vk_session.method('messages.send',
                                          {'user_id': event.user_id,
                                           'message': 'Здравствуй\n' +
                                           '1. да\n2. нет\n 3. Не знаю',
                                           'random_id': 0})
                        wait_next_round.append(event.user_id)
                    elif event.text == "2":
                        vk_session.method('messages.send',
                                          {'user_id': event.user_id,
                                           'message': 'Пока, друг!',
                                           'random_id': 0})
                    else:
                        vk_session.method('messages.send',
                                          {'user_id': event.user_id,
                                           'message': 'Я вас не понял',
                                           'random_id': 0})


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```